# filtering list of elements with specific value

Tags: python, list

I have a list as below, and I want to filter my list according to specific number/value.

```
a=[(2012,2013),
 (2012,2014),
 (2012,2015),
 (2012,2016),
]
b=2016
```

desire output

```
[(2012,2016)]
```

How can I manage to get the desire output, someone please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you trying to find a tuple based on its second element? (In your example, ´b=2016´.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filter in a list comprehension](https://realpython.com/lessons/filtering-elements-list-comprehensions/):

```py
a = [(2012, 2013),
     (2012, 2014),
     (2012, 2015),
     (2012, 2016),
     ]
b = 2016

result = [element for element in a if b in element]
print(result)  # [(2012, 2016)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension as:

```
a=[(2012,2013),
 (2012,2014),
 (2012,2015),
 (2012,2016),
]
b=2016

res = [elt for elt in a if b in elt]
print(res)
```